# What's the correct way for dynamically inserting a row in a table in Angular?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to insert a row in a table in Angular, for the purpose of showing information about the object in the clicked row. The data is fetched from a service. I've tried different approaches, [this one](http://plnkr.co/edit/weMFbzpxl18fWJqW13mp?p=preview) is what got me the closest. Unfortunately the renderer2.setRootElement() method removes the contents of the clicked row. Secondly it seems like working like this isn't recommended in Angular.

template:

```
  <tbody #tbody>
    <tr class="row" *ngFor="let ticket of tickets; let i=index"  (click)="createInfoBox($event, i, ticket)" id="row_{{i}}">
    <td class="col-md-1" id="ticket_state"> {{ ticket["AsstDoc.ProcState"] }}</td>
    <td class="col-md-2" id="ticket_date">{{ ticket["AsstDoc.DocDate"] }}</td>
    <td class="col-md-4" id="ticket_office">{{ ticket["AsstDoc.CustName"] }} {{ ticket["AsstDoc.DeliveryAddrNo"] || ticket["Addr.Line1"] }}</td>
    <td class="col-md-4" id="ticket_shortdescr">{{ ticket["AsstDoc.IntermedText"] || ticket["AsstDocItem.IntermedText"] || ticket.json }}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
```

onClick:

```
  createInfoBox($event, index, ticket) {
    this.renderer.selectRootElement(`#row_${index}`).insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<tr><td colspan="5">inserted content</td></tr>');
  }
```

I also tried [another approach](http://plnkr.co/edit/9poykk2uD2zIJp0UOBqy?p=preview), with a directive that should find all the rows and create a QueryList of results, from which then I could retrieve the index to the clicked row, and create a sibling. The querylist comes up empty.

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'tr'
})
export class Rows {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}

@ViewChildren(Rows) children: QueryList<Rows>;
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log( this.children)
  this.children.changes.subscribe((comps: QueryList <Rows>) =>
  {
    console.log("comps",comps);
  });
}
```

All the examples I've seen today have gotten me confused, what would be the correct approach in my case ?

Comment: I ended up putting up a modal window with ng-bootstrap, it looked better and felt better than what I was trying to accomplish above

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your tr in an ng-template then use a boolean + ngIf to render/unrender a new row with additional info

```
// component.html
<tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let ticket of tickets">
        <tr (click)="createInfoBox(ticket)">
            <td class="col-md-1">{{ ticket["AsstDoc.ProcState"] }}</td>
            <td class="col-md-2">{{ ticket["AsstDoc.DocDate"] }}</td>
            <td class="col-md-4">{{ ticket["AsstDoc.CustName"] }} {{ ticket["AsstDoc.DeliveryAddrNo"] || ticket["Addr.Line1"] }}</td>
            <td class="col-md-4">{{ ticket["AsstDoc.IntermedText"] || ticket["AsstDocItem.IntermedText"] || ticket.json }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngIf="ticket.showAdditionalInfo">
            <td colspan="5">inserted content</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
</tbody>

//component.ts
createInfoBox(ticket) {
    // toggle render of additional row
    ticket.showAdditionalInfo = !ticket.showAdditionalInfo;
}
```

Note: you'll need additional logic if you want to close all open rows when a new row is open

Answer (score 1):

would something like this work:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let ticket of tickets; let i=index">
<tr class="row" (click)="updateInfoRow($event, i, ticket)" id="row_{{i}}">
    <td class="col-md-1" id="ticket_state"> {{ ticket["AsstDoc.ProcState"] }}    </td>
    <td class="col-md-2" id="ticket_date">{{ ticket["AsstDoc.DocDate"] }}</td>
    <td class="col-md-4" id="ticket_office">{{ ticket["AsstDoc.CustName"] }} {{     ticket["AsstDoc.DeliveryAddrNo"] || ticket["Addr.Line1"] }}</td>
    <td class="col-md-4" id="ticket_shortdescr">{{     ticket["AsstDoc.IntermedText"] || ticket["AsstDocItem.IntermedText"] ||     ticket.json }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="info-row">
     <td>{{infoRows[i].SomeField</td>
     ... more tds ...
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

In the component:

```
infoRows = [];

ngOnInit() {
  for(int i = 0; i < tickets.length; i++){
     infoRows.push({});
  }
}

updateInfoRow(event, i, ticket) {
  infoRow[i] = { myField, ticket.myField } // or set from the server
}
```

So all the rows are there. You could just hide them, or *ngIf them so they aren't displayed until the click. Then you populate the data in a behind the scenes array which you can bind to in the tr based on the index.